# Is Firebase version 9.2.1 available or not?

Tags: android, firebase

[UPDATED]
After I updated Google Repository to the latest everything worked fine! Thank you @al-zill!

※ On July 14, 2016(Thu.)

The Firebase's get started guide says that the latest version is 9.2.1.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

However, when I try add the Firebase libraries, it gives me an error that looks like below:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1.
  Required by:
    my-project:my-app:unspecified
    <a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

which looks like the library with version 9.2.1 is not available just yet.

After specifying 9.2.0, everything just works fine.

Is 9.2.1 not available yet and the documentation is wrong?

Comment: what is your google repository version in android SDK?Is it already newest?

Comment: try to update the newest of google play services and google repository in your android SDK. I tried it yesterday it work fine in my project.

Comment: Go to Help > Check for updates...

Assuming you are using switched to Canary Channel.
If found any update, simply update it. I'm using 9.2.1 in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as @al-zill told me, after I update the Google Repository to the latest version everything worked fine. Thank you @al-zill!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that version 9.2.1 can be uses as of July 14 ... I use the following in my gradle successfully now:

```
// Android Studio 2.2 Preview 4 with Firebase 9.2.1 (emulator works now too)
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
```